# How to handle multiple subscriptions in the elm architecture

Tags: elm, elm-architecture

I am working through the elm guide.

In the effects subchapter there is an example with a Time-subscription

```
subscriptions : Model -> Sub Msg
subscriptions model =
  Time.every second Tick
```

and an example which handles Web-Sockets-subscriptions

```
subscriptions : Model -> Sub Msg
subscriptions model =
  WebSocket.listen "ws://echo.websocket.org" NewMessage
```

But in these examples, there is only ever one subscription.
How could I handle multiple subscriptions?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

You may use `Sub.batch`, providing a list of subscriptions, it returns a batched subscription

Reference:

- [Elm 0.19 docs](https://package.elm-lang.org/packages/elm/core/1.0.2/Platform-Sub#batch)
- [Pre-0.19 docs](http://package.elm-lang.org/packages/elm-lang/core/5.1.1/Platform-Sub#batch)